# Generate count column for IDs in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here how you can generate the dummy version of my Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

usr_id = [121,121,121,121,135,135,135,135,135,135,135,135,135]
ses_id = [95,95,95,108,97,97,97,97,98,98,98,101,101]
que_id = [1,8,15,23,1,42,9,5,7,9,10,17,20]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(usr_id, ses_id, que_id)),
               columns =['usr_id', 'ses_id', 'que_id'])
```

| usr_id | ses_id | que_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 95 | 1 |
| 121 | 95 | 8 |
| 121 | 95 | 15 |
| 121 | 108 | 23 |
| 135 | 97 | 1 |
| 135 | 97 | 42 |
| 135 | 97 | 9 |
| 135 | 97 | 5 |
| 135 | 98 | 7 |
| 135 | 98 | 9 |
| 135 | 98 | 10 |
| 135 | 101 | 17 |
| 135 | 101 | 20 |

A user can attempt multiple sessions where each sesssion can have varying number of multiple questions. I need to create two columns which will number the session and question i.e, (session number or question number 1, 2, 3...) for each indiviudal users. Something like this:

| usr_id | ses_id | que_id | ses_no | que_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 95 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 121 | 95 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 121 | 95 | 15 | 1 | 3 |
| 121 | 108 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| 135 | 97 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 135 | 97 | 42 | 1 | 2 |
| 135 | 97 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 135 | 97 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 135 | 98 | 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 135 | 98 | 9 | 2 | 2 |
| 135 | 98 | 10 | 2 | 3 |
| 135 | 101 | 17 | 3 | 1 |
| 135 | 101 | 20 | 3 | 2 |

So session_id 95 was the first session usr_id 121 attempted within which he attempted three questions que_id 1, 8 & 15. Next session attempted by the same user is ses_id 108 with only 1 question que_id 23. Another user, usr_id 135 atempted it's first session recorded as ses_id 97 in which he attempted four questions que_id 1, 42, 9 & 5. The second session from the same user now is ses_id 98 and so on.

I managed to generate the 'que_no' using the following:

```
df['que_no'] = df.groupby('ses_id').cumcount()+1
```

But could't find a way to do the same for ses_no.

I am also having an idea of using `.shift()` to compare whether there is a change in 'usr_id' and/or 'ses_id and some how apply a count logic on the output. Something like this:

```
i = df.usr_id
j = df.sess_id

i_shift_ne = i.ne(i.shift())
j_shift_ne = j.ne(j.shift())
```

Not sure whether this idea will work or not also I am pretty sure there has to be a smarter way of doing this. It will be great if we can make it happen using pandas library itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use custom lambda function per `usr_id` with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['ses_no'] = df.groupby('usr_id')['ses_id'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1
#if values are sorted
#df['ses_no'] = df.groupby('usr_id')['ses_id'].rank(method='dense').astype(int) 

df['que_no'] = df.groupby(['usr_id','ses_no']).cumcount()+1
print (df)
    usr_id  ses_id  que_id  ses_no  que_no
0      121      95       1       1       1
1      121      95       8       1       2
2      121      95      15       1       3
3      121     108      23       2       1
4      135      97       1       1       1
5      135      97      42       1       2
6      135      97       9       1       3
7      135      97       5       1       4
8      135      98       7       2       1
9      135      98       9       2       2
10     135      98      10       2       3
11     135     101      17       3       1
12     135     101      20       3       2
```